# How to use php regular get the 2ed and 3rd `<div class="partright">`?

Tags: php, html, regex

There have some texts, how to use php regular get the 2ed and 3rd `<div class="partright">`? Thanks.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content>
    <div class="partleft">
    text1
    </div>
    <div class="partright">
    text2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content>
    <div class="partleft">
    text3
    </div>
    <div class="partright">
    text4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content>
    <div class="partleft">
    text5
    </div>
    <div class="partright">
    text6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want output

```
<div class="partright">
text4
</div>
<div class="partright">
text6
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very incomplete but I assume your talking about traversing the elements to modify them in some way.

You should look at the following library called [SimpleDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

And usage would be like:

```
require_once 'simple_dom.class.php';

$html = "<html_data_here>";
$html = str_get_html($html);

foreach($html->find(".partleft:nth(2),.partleft:nth(3)") as $p)
{
    echo $p->outerText;
}
```

**Note**: The above is an example and may not work as expected, for working examples please see the Simple Dom site linked above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) use SimpleXML indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a regular expression that would match

```
<div class="partright">(.*)</div>
```

Put all matches in an array and take the 2nd and third element from the array.